# webpack, electron and express : Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object

Tags: javascript, import, webpack, require

I am trying to run express with electron, and encountered the "Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object" error, which is said to be an webpack issue. Then I modified my code so there is no mixed import and require, but the error is still there. It confused me that the error is *ONLY* involved with my express wrapper module, while the electron module itself works fine with `require`, I have no idea now. here is my `main.js`:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
// after comment the next line, the error would not appear
const { runExpress } = require('../express/app-wrapper')
// ..other codes..
```

and my `app-wrapper.js`(some logger codes omitted):

```
var app = require('./app')
var http = require('http')

var port = 3000
var server = http.createServer(app)

function runExpress () {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    // apply errorHandlers, for the webpack middlewares
    // needs to apply before these errorHandlers.
    for (let handler of app.errorHandlers) {
      app.use(handler)
    }

    /**
     * Get port from environment and store in Express.
     */
    app.set('port', port)
    /**
     * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
     */

    server.listen(port)
    server.on('error', onError)
    server.on('listening', () => { resolve() })
  })
}

module.exports = {
  app,
  port,
  runExpress
}
```

(well, it is not a good idea to run express inside electron, but my curiousity is bitting me, thanks for help)